# Is TCP Buffer In Address Space Of Process Memory?

Tags: networking, tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming, operating-system

I am told to increase TCP buffer size in order to process messages faster.
My Question is, no matter what buffer i am using for TCP message(ByteBuffer, DirectByteBuffer etc),  whenever CPU receives interrupt from say NIC, to handle network request to read the socket data, does OS maintain any buffer in memory outside Address Space of requesting process(i.g. the process which is listening on that socket)

or

whatever way CPU receives network data, it will always be written in a buffer of process address space only and no buffer(including 'Recv-Q' and 'Send-Q' of netstat command) outside of the address space is maintained for this communication?

Answer (score 1):

The process by which the Linux network stack receives data is a bit complicated. I wrote a [comprehensive guide to the Linux network stack](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/06/22/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/) that explains everything you need to know starting from the device driver up to a userland program's socket receive queue.

There are many places buffers are maintained in the kernel:

1. The DMA ring where packets are written by the NIC after they've arrived.
2. References to the packets on the DMA ring are used to process the packet.
3. Eventually, the packet data is added to process' receive queue, if the receive queue is not full already.
4. Reads from the socket will pull packets from the process' receive queue.
5. If packet sniffing is occurring, packet data is duplicated and sent to any filters added by the packet sniffing code.

The full process of how data is moved, accounted for, and dropped (when required) is described in the blog post linked above.

Now, if you want to process messages faster, I assume you mean you want to reduce your packet processing latency, correct? If so, you should consider using [`SO_BUSYPOLL`](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/06/22/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/#busy-polling-for-low-latency-sockets) which can help reduce packet processing latency.

Increasing the receive buffer just increases the number of packets that can be queued for a userland socket. To increasing packet processing power, you need to carefully monitor and tune each component of the network stack. You may need to use something like RPS to increase the number of CPUs processing packets.

You will also want to monitor each component of your network stack to ensure that available buffers and CPU processing power is sufficient to handle your packet workload.

Answer (score 0):

You are being told to increase the socket send or receive buffer sizes. These are associated with the socket, in the TCP part of the kernel. See `setsockopt()` and `SO_RCVBUF` and `SO_SNDBUF`.

Answer (score 0):

See:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt

The options are SO_SNDBUF, and SO_RCVBUF. If you directly use the C-API, the call is setsockopt itself. If you use some kind of framework look up how to set socket options. This is indeed a kernel-side buffer, not one held by your process. It determines how many bytes the kernel can hold ready for you to fetch from a call to read/receive. It also affects the [flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control) mechanism of TCP.