# Where data is stored when bytearray got filled

Tags: java, nio

I am using non blocking serversocket .I have allocated ByteArray size as 100.Then, client send 200 byte size data to server, server receives 200 byte message as 100 byte + 100 byte data.My question is, after read 100 byte from channel, where remaining 100 byte data are stored till read() is called again.thanks(sorry if any grammer mistake)

server program:

```
public class SelectorExample {

    public static void main (String [] args)
        throws IOException {

        // Get selector
        Selector selector = Selector.open();

        System.out.println("Selector open: " + selector.isOpen());

        // Get server socket channel and register with selector
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();

        InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new 
        InetSocketAddress("131.10.20.16", 5454);
        serverSocket.socket().bind(hostAddress,0);
        serverSocket.configureBlocking(false);
        int ops = serverSocket.validOps();
        SelectionKey selectKy = serverSocket.register(selector, ops, null);

        for (;;) {
            System.out.println("Waiting for select...");
            int noOfKeys = selector.select();
            System.out.println("Number of selected keys: " + noOfKeys);
            Set selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator iter = selectedKeys.iterator();

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey ky = (SelectionKey)iter.next();
                if (ky.isAcceptable()) {                     
                // Accept the new client connection
                SocketChannel client = serverSocket.accept();
                client.configureBlocking(false);

                // Add the new connection to the selector
                client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

                System.out.println("Accepted new connection from client: " + client);                     
            }
            else if (ky.isReadable()) {

                // Read the data from client
                SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) ky.channel();
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
                int i =client.read(buffer);
                String output = new String(buffer.array());

                System.out.println("Message read from client: " + output);

                if (i == -1) {
                    client.close();
                    System.out.println("Client messages are complete; close.");
                }

            } // end if (ky...)

            iter.remove();

        } // end while loop

    } // end for loop
}
```

Comment: This gives you a good description: [Is TCP Buffer In Address Space Of Process Memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38735424/is-tcp-buffer-in-address-space-of-process-memory)

Comment: In the TCP socket receive buffer in the kernel, or networking stack

Comment: @EJP Is there any time limit  to read from buffer in the kernel, or networking stack??

Comment: No there isn't, unless the peer resets the connection. Why do you ask? NB you should check for -1 *before* printing the message, and when you do print the message you should use `new String(buffer.array(), 0, buffer.position());`

Comment: @EJP i got it. thanks